# Mobile Fu gem not working on ruby 1.8.7 / rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Installing the gem following the instructions on http://rubygems.org/gems/mobile-fu ("Simply add `gem 'mobile-fu'` to your Gemfile and run bundle install") works OK, and the gem is listed as installed and all needed dependencies are also in place AFAIK, below is the relevant part of the projects Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'rails', '~> 2.3.14'
gem 'aslakjo-comatose', '2.0.5.12', :require => 'comatose'
gem 'adamwiggins-rest-client', '1.0.4'
gem 'ruby-hmac', '0.4', :require => 'hmac'
gem 'ruby-net-ldap', '0.0.4', :require => 'net/ldap'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.11'
gem 'hpricot', '0.8.2'
gem 'oauth', '0.3.6'
gem 'sanitize', '1.1.0'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '1.1.0', :require => 'sunspot/rails'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'rdoc', :require => 'rdoc'
gem 'to_xls'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'jammit'
gem 'rabl', '~>0.6'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.7'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'mobile-fu', '~> 1.1.0'
...
```

Here is the resulting error message/log when starting the server: "no such file to load -- mobile/fu (MissingSourceFile)" being the main problem (IMHO):

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': no such file to load -- mobile/fu (MissingSourceFile)
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config/boot.rb:116:in `load_gems'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from ./config/environment.rb:7
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1
    from ./script/server:3:in `eval'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:78
    from ./script/server:3:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
```

**Update 1**

Using the solution described by Ben Langfeld ("You can fix this using the following in your Gemfile: `gem 'mobile-fu', '~> 1.1.0', :require => 'mobile-fu'`") only produces a new error shown below:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require': no such file to load -- rails (MissingSourceFile)
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/mobile-fu-1.1.0/lib/mobile-fu.rb:1
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config/boot.rb:116:in `load_gems'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from ./config/environment.rb:7
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/work/web/srv/config.ru:1
    from ./script/server:3:in `eval'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@srv/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:78
    from ./script/server:3:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
```

There are no minimum versions of ruby or rails listed for this gem, but I suspect the problem is caused by the old versions we are running. However, upgrading ruby or rails is not an option, because this is a maintenance project.

If any replacement gems for Mobile Fu with similar capabilities exists that is know to work on our ruby & rails version/config, that is an alternate option we are willing to look into if this issue cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mobile-fu', '~> 1.1.0', :require => 'mobile-fu'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but unfortunately I've already tried that solution, and it only leads to another similar error (see the added update 1 above).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Mobile Fu gem is not compatible with ruby 1.8.x / rails 2.3.x, we ended up creating our own similar functionality based on the following article: http://erniemiller.org/2011/01/05/mobile-devices-and-rails-maintaining-your-sanity/